# Proof checking : If $\{h\in\mathcal{H}:||h||\leq1\}$ is compact, then $\text{dim}\mathcal{H}<\infty$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am going through the functional analysis book by John B. Conway. I have a problem

> If $\{h\in\mathcal{H}:||h||\leq1\}$ is compact, show that $\text{dim}\mathcal{H}<\infty$.

Where $\mathcal{H}$ is Hilbert space. My proof is following :

> Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$ with infinite cardinality, and let $$U:=\cup_{e\in\mathcal{E}}U_e:=\cup_{e\in\mathcal{E}}\{h\in\mathcal{H}:||h-e/2||\leq 1/200\}.$$ 
>   Then $U\subset \{h\in\mathcal{H}:||h||\leq 1\}$ because for all $h\in\mathcal{H}$, $$||h-e/2||<1/200\Rightarrow||h||=||h-e/2+e/2||\leq||h-e/2||+||e/2||<1$$ for some $e\in\mathcal{E}$. Now take open cover $\{V_e\}_{e\in\mathcal{E}}$ of $U$, where $$V_i:=\{h\in\mathcal{H}:||h-e/2||< 1/100\}.$$ Then $\{V_e\}_{e\in\mathcal{E}}$ is pairwise disjoint : let $e,e'\in\mathcal{E}$, $e\neq e'$, $h\in V_e$, and $h'\in V_{e'}$. Then $$\begin{align}||h-h'||&=||h-e/2+e/2-e'/2-(h'-e'/2)||\\&\geq\bigg|||h-e/2-(h'-e'/2)||-||e/2-e'/2||\bigg|\\&=\bigg|||h-e/2-(h'-e'/2)||-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\bigg|\\&\geq\bigg|\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{1}{50}\bigg|>0.\end{align}$$ 
>   Therefore from $U$ is closed and $U$ is not compact, $U\subset\{h\in\mathcal{H}:||h||\leq 1\}$ is not compact.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: $\{h:\|h\|<1\}$ can never be compact unless your space is $\{0\}$.  You should distinguish between $<$ and $\leq $.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, you are right. I edited.

Comment: It is hard in your question to see: (1) which subset is declared to be compact as $U$ is not the same subset than the closed unit ball (2) how you get the conclusion that this set is not compact.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes, I wrote $\mathcal{H}$ instead of $\{h\in\mathcal{H}:||h||\leq 1\}$. I fixed it.

Comment: Why is $U$ closed? You have written it as a countable union of closed balls, which does not imply that it is closed. That said a much much simpler proof is to note that what you call $\mathcal E$ is an infinite and discrete set, hence it admits sequences without any limit points. Since $\mathcal E$ is a subset of the unit ball the unit ball cannot be compact.

Comment: @s.harp $U$ is closed because : For any converging sequence $\{h_n\}$ and it's limit $h$ (which exists since $\mathcal{H}$ is Hilbert space), if you take $N$ large enough so that for all $n\geq N$ $\{h_n\}_{n\geq N}$ are in the same ball (this is possible since every ball is pairwise disjoint with positive distance $\sqrt{2}/2$), then the ball is closed hence $h$ is in the ball. And thank you for the much simpler proof! That deserves the answer I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof basically makes use of the fact that the elements of the ONB $\mathcal E$ all have mutual distance $1$. The set $U$ is a sort of blown up version of $\mathcal E/2$ and is unnecessary: Your argument that $U$ is closed works just as well for $\mathcal E$.

A more simple and direct way to exploit this fact is to consider a sequence in $\mathcal E$ hitting no element more than once (possible iff $H$ is infinite dimensional). Since all the elements of $\mathcal E$ have mutual distance $1$ there cannot be any subsequence that is Cauchy, in particular no convergent subsequence is possible. Since $\mathcal E$ is in the unit ball you find that the unit ball cannot be compact.

Comment: Yeah, that is ‘the proof’ I guess. Thanks!